# Add column of dense vectors over a groupby in pyspark 2.2 or 2.3

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I am using Pyspark 2.2.

I have a input table like this:

```
tag | features
1   | [1,0,0,2]
2   | [1.5,0,1,0]
2   | [0,0,1,0]
```

Need output like this

```
tag | sum(features)
1   | [1,0,0,2]
2   | [1.5,0,2,0]
```

Element wise addition needs to happen.
So far I have is:

```
df.groupBy('tag').agg(F.sum('features')).show(5,0)
```

But this gives me an error:

```
cannot resolve 'sum(`features`)' due to data type mismatch: function sum requires numeric types, not ArrayType(FloatType,true)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:   I have used `F.collect_list` to group all lists together

Step 2:   Created a UDF by name Sum1() to take lists as input  and return the sum

```
  from pyspark.sql.types import *
    from datetime import datetime
    from pyspark.sql import *
    from collections import *
    from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
    from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
    df= spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            (1, [1,0,0,2]), 
            (2, [2,0,1,0]),
            (2, [0,0,1,0])
            ],("ID","List")
        )
    df2=df.groupby("id").agg(F.collect_list("List") ).withColumnRenamed('collect_list(List)', 'List')
    df2.registerTempTable("dfTbl")
    def sum1(List):
      d=[]
      for i in range(0,len(List[0])):
        if(len(List)==1 or len(List)==0):
            d.append(List[0][i])
        else:   
            d.append(List[0][i]+List[1][i])
      return d
    spark.udf.register("sum12", sum1, returnType=ArrayType(StringType()))
    spark.sql("select id,sum12(List) from dfTbl ").show()
```

Comment: It is very slow for my dataset. Although I do get how to proceed.

Comment: try to use  persist()  data, hope it will be faster